# Snowflake .net connector certificate error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having trouble using .net connector (https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net). It works from browser/Tableau/Excel. For tableau/excel I have to pass CaBundleFile.

Is there a way to pass a certificate file (CaBundleFile) using the .net connector?

I am getting following error.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not
 establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the ODBC driver, Snowflake doesn’t perform OCSP checking for .NET driver which uses the underlying .NET framework for checking validity of the HTTPS certificate.

One thing that might help is looking through similar GitHub issues for ideas (they discuss upgrading and network traces):
https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/issues/6

You might also try looking at some of the Microsoft docs and forums for the error on some troubleshooting ideas:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsanders/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure

Comment: thanks for prompt response. I couldnt get tracing working. I tried all steps mentioned on above microsoft link but it didnt create log file. However, as a test when I set remote server certificate validation as true I was able to connect. I think I might need to pass a valid certificate but dont see an option in the client api. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know of a way to set this in the client api.  I see you opened an issue so let's see if you get further response from the Dev team: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/issues/211